# Is It Redundant To Use "But" Before "Alas"?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Given the two sentences:

```
She spent months in the hospital; alas, the doctors couldn't save her.
She spent months in the hospital, but alas, the doctors couldn't save her.
```

In the second sentence, it seems the word "but" is unnecessary.

Comment: The punctuation is suspect in the second sentence. The first variant is totally acceptable. I'm finding the apparent twinning of 'save' with 'months in the hospital' somewhat more jarring than twinning 'but' with 'alas'.  I assume 'they' equates to 'the medical staff'. << He planted two hundred tulip bulbs, but alas, only two dozen tulips grew.' >> looks and sounds fine. Assuming you're not averse to a bit of a literary style (and deleting the 'but' makes it a lot more of a literary style: positively Dumbledorian).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. Updated the punctuation based on your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not redundant to use "but" before "alas" if you want to show a contrast in your writing. For instance, take a look at this title from The New York Times:

> She's Lovely, But Alas, She's Only Software.

But you can also use "alas" alone. The New Oxford American Dictionary gives this sentence as an example:

> alas, my funds have some limitations.

So, all in all, if you are going to show a contrast in your writing, feel free to use "but" before "alas"; otherwise, you may use "alas" alone.